# DataGrid - a clean way to display unrelated cell values in a row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and I'll try to keep this one short.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display a table, in which cell values are unrelated to each other and each one represents a seperate object.

To be more precise, I need a calendar-like view with associated tasks on each day, like this:

[image: table structure]

**The number of displayed days is variable.**
What matters is that days are listed chrolonogically and the order of tasks on a specific day is preserved (pretty much like it was a list of ListBoxes).

So how do I achieve that?

DataGrid seems to only bind rows to data. I thought of implementing a list of adapters with variable number of DependencyProperties which would pretend to be rows. But this seems to be a bit too much complicated for such a simple table.

I also looked into how to make DataGrid horizontal, but it's even more additional code.

Any help apreciated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* just use a `ListBox`, or even just an `ItemsControl` for each day and have any number of them... you just need to structure your data correctly. Let's say you have a `Day` class with a `Date` and a collection called `Tasks`:

```
public class Day // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly here
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view model, you just need a collection of `Day` instances:

```
public ObservableCollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
```

Then you just need a `DataTemplate` to define your `ListBox` for each `Day` instance:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:Day}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MMM d}}" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, add a `ListBox`, or `ItemsControl` to display the collection of `Day`s and set the `ItemsPanel` to a `StackPanel` with its `Orientation` property set to `Horizontal`:

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Days}" Name="overlayItems">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Add some test data and your away:

```
Days = new ObservableCollection<Day>();
Days.Add(new Day() { Date = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1), Tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Doing something today", "Doing something else today" } });
Days.Add(new Day() { Date = new DateTime(2014, 5, 2), Tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Doing nothing today" } });
Days.Add(new Day() { Date = new DateTime(2014, 5, 3), Tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Doing something today" } });
```

I'll leave the finer details to you.

Comment: Due to lack of an easier solution, I'll go with this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a View Model object called `AppointmentViewModel` which has all of the tasks that are scheduled to be done on that day.  You could then create a View Model class for one row called a `WeekViewModel`, for example.  That then could have one property for each day:

```
public class WeekViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public AppointmentViewModel Sunday { get { . . . } set { . . . } }

    public AppointmentViewModel Monday { get { . . . } set { . . . } }

   // and so on for the rest of the week
}
```

Then, you would have a View Model object for the form with the `DataGrid` control in it.  This would have a property that is of type `WeekViewModel`.  Let's call the collection property `Appointments`.

The XAML for the `DataGrid` would look something like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Appointments}"
          Name="ThisMonthsAppointmentsGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sunday}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Monday}" />
        <!-- Other DataGridTextColumn definitions for other days of the week -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This is what I meant saying "a list of adapters". Unfortunately, the number of displayed days is variable, so I would have to dynamically register DependencyProperties. Thanks for your time though